# Laravel queue, supervisor is running but not processing jobs

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, queue

I'm using supervisor with laravel on ubuntu
there are many jobs in jobs table but they are not processing

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/queue-worker.conf

```
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/site/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3 -->
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/site/storage/logs/worker.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

sudo supervisorctl status queue-worker:*

```
queue-worker:queue-worker_00     RUNNING   pid 1527816, uptime 0:36:16
queue-worker:queue-worker_01     RUNNING   pid 1527820, uptime 0:36:16
queue-worker:queue-worker_02     RUNNING   pid 1527804, uptime 0:36:17
queue-worker:queue-worker_03     RUNNING   pid 1527802, uptime 0:36:17
queue-worker:queue-worker_04     RUNNING   pid 1527815, uptime 0:36:16
queue-worker:queue-worker_05     RUNNING   pid 1527793, uptime 0:36:17
queue-worker:queue-worker_06     RUNNING   pid 1527835, uptime 0:36:16
queue-worker:queue-worker_07     RUNNING   pid 1527807, uptime 0:36:17
```

also i run this command

```
sudo php artisan queue:restart
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What queue driver are you using? sqs or database? When using supervisor, u dont need run artisan command manually.

Comment: @AndreHaykal database

Comment: I would also advice to use redis with [Laravel Horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/horizon#introduction) for queue processing if you depend heavily on those jobs. It's easy to setup and can be fully used with supervisor.

Comment: @AndreHaykal `queue:restart` has nothing to do with supervisor, it can be called whenever you want, with or without supervisor.

Answer (score 2):

You said you are using `database` on a comment, how do you expect to process jobs if you are running `php artisan queue:work sqs`, you are literally executing the `SQS` queue, not database...

So use this `command=php /var/www/site/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3` (or just run without writting `database`, but `QUEUE_CONNECTION` env must be `database`)